# Filter Pandas data frame based on criteria - fails on NaN values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to filter a Pandas data frame based on a criteria (Python 2.7):

```
data[data['a']=='bbb']
```

But some of the values in the series data['a'] are NaN and I get an error:
`invalid type comparison`.

How can I ignore it and treat the NaN as not matching the criteria thus filtering it out?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reassign the column type as follows:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('O')
```

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
data[(data['a']=='bbb') & (data['a'].notnull())]
```

Sample:

```
print data
      a
0   bbb
1   bbb
2   bbb
3   bbb
4   bbb
5   bbb
6   bbb
7   NaN
8     a
9     a
10  bbb

print data[(data['a']=='bbb') & (data['a'].notnull())]
      a
0   bbb
1   bbb
2   bbb
3   bbb
4   bbb
5   bbb
6   bbb
10  bbb
```